# DependencyProperty PropertyChangedCallback problem

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

Sorry for my English. 
I try to write UserControl (SearchTextBox...simmillar Firefox search textbox) that consists from TextBox, Popup and ListBox in a Popup. I need to change ItemsSource of ListBox dynamically in my application. So i use DependencyProperty in UserControl:

```
//STextBox UserControl Code-Behind
public partial class STextBox : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty;

   static STextBox()
   {
        ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource",   typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(STextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));
    }

   public IEnumerable ItemsSource
   {
       get
       {
           return (IEnumerable)GetValue(STextBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(STextBox.ItemsSourceProperty, value);
       }
   }

   private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      STextBox c = (STextBox)d;
      c.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
   }
```

I can't use bindings to ItemsSource in my app, because two lists for my ListBox-ItemsSource creates on the fly from records of database. I set ItemsSource in code:
    //my app code-behind

```
  switch (SomeIF)
        {
            case 0:
                sTextBox.ItemsSource = list1;
                break;

            case 1:
                sTextBox.ItemsSource = list2;
                break;
        }
```

But nothing happened. I know exactly that OnItemsSourceChanged method is fired, but new value never assigned to ItemsSource. What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you use the ItemsSource property of your UserControl? Do you bind it somewhere?

Comment: No, i dont using Bindings of my UserControl

Comment: Then what do you expect to happen when you assign ItemsSource? If this property is not used anywhere, of course nothing will happed... You probably need to bind it to the ListBox's ItemsSource property.

Comment: @mirymir I've created simple project reproducing your problem and... everything works well. Maybe you should describe situation with more details or even provide project for testing.

Comment: @Pavlo I expect that ItemsSource of my ListBox will be set to list1 or to list2, but this not happened. I can't use bindings because list1 and list2 creates on-the-fly as i wrote.

Comment: @Alex it's strange...Nothing else...i mean that I describe my issue as fully as I can.... i'll try it on the blank project. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Can not say that I liked, but this solution work.

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  STextBox c = (STextBox)d;
  c.OnItemsSourceChanged(e);  
}

//added overload method where I can simply set property to the control
protected virtual void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   myListBox.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
}
```